# How to request pages_show_list permission with Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

1. I tried 2 way, one in the `Facebook Developer site` find permission request with this name, I couldn't find it.
2. add as a 4th parameter to the `Facebook Login Button`, it did not help

```
<FacebookLogin
appId={fbAppId}
autoLoad={true}
fields="name,email,picture,pages_show_list"
onClick={this.componentClicked}
callback={this.responseFacebook}
/>
```

Do you have any other idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The Facebook API works like this, 
   Development Mode: For development mode you can try to access pages which were associated with the account in which app created. So, that pages associated with that user can be accessible. You can retrieve the pages using following link,

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/accounts/

Live mode: In case of live mode you need to create a video of snapshot using your development mode functionality and get "pages_show_list" permission approved. Then you can access the pages details associated with authenticated users.

2. For login button you can try like this,

```
fb:login-button size="large" scope="public_profile,email,pages_show_list,read_insights,manage_pages" onlogin="checkLoginState();"
```

which gives you token and use that token to get pages associated with user account.

Comment: Hi! So if app is not production / review ready, but only developers use it, I need to pass `pages_show_list` in `scope`. Right?

Comment: And I need to pass `pages_show_list` as `scope` parameter, and not as `fields`. :(

Comment: First you need to authenticate user using above login button for permission pages_show_list in order to get access_token. And once the user goes through above procedure your app will get permission to access user data. For that you have to pass that permission in scope section. Once you get the access token then you can pass that to graph api endpoint mentioned in above url to get pages associated with that user.

Comment: Hello all. I posted a similar question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77891331/cant-see-how-to-add-pages-show-list-to-my-facebook-app-in-development-mode

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the js SDK of Facebook then there is an option to ask permission through SDK  functions.

```
FB.login(function(response) {
  // handle the response
}, {scope: 'public_profile,email,..other persmissionlist'});
```

**Note:-**

1. Use this concept only when your app is in the testing phase and
   wants to create a request for permission in App Review or there are
   some permissions enabled but you want only a few.
2. Use this approach with Test users only.

**Reference link:-**

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web#re-asking-declined-permissions