# Can't see how to add "pages_show_list" to my Facebook App in development mode

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

In the official documentation they says :

##################################################

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/permissions/

App Review  is required for all permissions except for email and public_profile if your app needs access to data that you do not own or manage

##################################################

From the Graph API Explorer, because I need to get the page access token, I enter :

```
/me/accounts/
```

But I got the message "The field 'accounts' is only accessible on the User object after the user grants one of the following permissions: 'pages_show_list'."

My app is in development mode.

So I tried to request this permission when my facebook account is login to the app.

In my Facebook login code, I use :

```
FB.login(function(response) { 
// handle the response }, {scope: 'pages_show_list'}); 
};
```

And got this error ""Sorry, something went wrong. We're working on getting this fixed as soon as we can."

Anyway ,my app is in development mode and I logon to the app with my own facebook account, which has administrator role on the app (and which owns the page to where I want to post). So normally, I should even not need to ask for this permission right?

My business verification status is "Verified" already. I have also replied all the questions about Data Handling RGPD.

I don't need my app to be public actually, I just want to make some posts to the FB page that I manage with CURL.

Thanks

Comment: _"So normally, I should even not need to ask for this permission right?"_ - no, your user still needs to _grant_ the permission. Having a role on the app only makes a difference in terms of whether you _can_ ask the user for permissions that are not approved in review yet.

Comment: _"I don't need my app to be public actually, I just want to make some posts to the FB page that I manage with CURL."_ - you do need it to be public, if you want everyone to be able to _see_ the posts you make on the page; otherwise, they will show up for users with a role in the app only.

Comment: OK Thanks good to know. But do you have an idea why do I get an error and I ask for the permission in the Facebook login button {scope: 'pages_show_list'}?

Comment: Maybe you chose the wrong app type when you created it? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/create-an-app/other-app-types#step-3--select-an-app-type

Comment: Please note that {scope: 'public_profile'} works. So it is not an error related with the JS code I guess..

Comment: It works !! I had to create a new app and choose "Business" as app type. (You can't change the app type when your app is already created, you need to create new one, that is why was lost). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comment, I add to create a new app and select "Business" as app type (it is impossible to change it once the app is created, so you have to create a new one).